# Consumir Web Service Post C#

Tags: c#, webservice

Amigos, tengo que consumir un web service mediante el metodo post y c#
he probado desde postman el ws y funciona bien, lo tengo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el body lo envio asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en el codigo lo llamo de la siguente manera

```
            Resultado resul = null;
            HttpWebRequest request;
            request = WebRequest.Create("https://xxx/api/productosFactory/") as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Timeout = 10 * 1000;
            request.Method = "POST";
            //request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token 7350b87936cc3ed73b0a687e3ad6c025eb7666");
            request.Accept = "application/json";

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(moto);
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                resul = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Resultado>(result);
            }
            if (resul.resultado)
            { return true; }
            else
            { return false; }
```

en esta linea me da un error 404 solicitud incorrecta

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

Queria ver si me pueden ayudar como deberia crear mi codigo para que funcione el ws

Comment: Si te sirve de algo, yo uso RestSharp.  Lo bajo desde nuget al proyecto, y para generar el código desde postman una vez que tienes lista tu petición funcionando en la parte superior derecha hay un icono que tiene un simbolo de codigo: </> y te abre una sección  que te genera el código para esa biblioteca, solo copias y pegas y listo. Saludos!

Comment: estas seguro que va el parametro PreAutenticated? siempre uso la libreria HttpClient y nunca use ese parametro para mandar un token median Authorization

Answer (score 1):

Como te indico la respuesta anterior lo mas sencillo es que uses restsharp

te adjunto las imagenes.

[image: Agregas las referencias]

pero si no quieres usar una libreria de terceros puedes implementar el codigo en C#
para esto debes usar la clase HttpWebRequest (HttpClient es la manera mas moderna de consumir HTTP en .NET desde .Net 4.5) abajo encontraras un codigo que hace el consumo de un servicio por el metodo POST donde el content-type es de tipo form-data. para usarlo sustituye con tu URL y en la variable postData sustituye con tu datos.

static void Ejemplo2()
{
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/test/RelaisServlet/");

```
        var PostData = "<DMS TYPE=\"06\" CODE_INTERROGATION=\"2\" CHAMPS_CMPL=\"KGPZ90\" NumeroPoste=\"001\" PARAMDMS=\"124%C2%B0%C2%B0463\" />";
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        

        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundaryBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        //var HeaderTemplate = "--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\n\r{2}\r{0}--";
        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
        string header = String.Format(formdataTemplate,"xml" ,PostData);


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData) && request.Method == "POST")
        {
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            //var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(header);
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
            //request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writeStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
                writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                writeStream.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
            }
        }

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseValue = string.Empty;

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            // grab the response
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(responseValue);


        }

    }
```